How can I fix wrong mdadm.conf in a working raid 1?
I have a server linux with CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009.
Server has 2 disks with a raid1 software.
Raid1 seems ok, and if i run cat /proc/mdstat this is the output:
Personalities : [raid1] 
md124 : active raid1 sda5[0] sdb5[1]
      1943943232 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 2/15 pages [8KB], 65536KB chunk

md125 : active raid1 sdb4[1] sda4[0]
      4189184 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      
md126 : active raid1 sdb3[1] sda3[0]
      4189184 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      
md127 : active raid1 sdb2[1] sda2[0]
      1048512 blocks [2/2] [UU]
      
unused devices: <none>

Looking at Logwatch report i see this error in mdadm section:
mdadm: cannot open /dev/md2: No such file or directory /dev/md2 : 
mdadm: cannot open /dev/md3: No such file or directory /dev/md3 : 
mdadm: cannot open /dev/md4: No such file or directory /dev/md4 : 
mdadm: cannot open /dev/md5: No such file or directory /dev/md5 : 

So i checked the mdadm.conf file and it seems wrong:
MAILADDR root
ARRAY /dev/md2 level=raid1 num-devices=2 metadata=0.90 UUID=4e9d6540:6dbcd220:cf76e387:6b0e5184
ARRAY /dev/md3 level=raid1 num-devices=2 metadata=1.2 name=10907523:swap UUID=aa3c14ba:b8bcfeeb:1d3b6ca9:e50c9ff9
ARRAY /dev/md4 level=raid1 num-devices=2 metadata=1.2 name=10907523:tmp UUID=30792b3a:fdaa4031:24c14d19:978ef0eb
ARRAY /dev/md5 level=raid1 num-devices=2 metadata=1.2 name=10907523:root UUID=182ced2e:4d796d7f:13af9080:fdef98dd

Scanning raid with mdadm (mdadm --detail --scan) the result is:
ARRAY /dev/md/125_0 metadata=0.90 UUID=4e9d6540:6dbcd220:cf76e387:6b0e5184
ARRAY /dev/md/10907523:swap metadata=1.2 name=10907523:swap UUID=aa3c14ba:b8bcfeeb:1d3b6ca9:e50c9ff9
ARRAY /dev/md/10907523:tmp metadata=1.2 name=10907523:tmp UUID=30792b3a:fdaa4031:24c14d19:978ef0eb
ARRAY /dev/md/10907523:root metadata=1.2 name=10907523:root UUID=182ced2e:4d796d7f:13af9080:fdef98dd

Informations about block devices with lsblk return:
NAME      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda         8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk  
|-sda1      8:1    0    1M  0 part  
|-sda2      8:2    0    1G  0 part  
| `-md127   9:127  0 1024M  0 raid1 /boot
|-sda3      8:3    0    4G  0 part  
| `-md126   9:126  0    4G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
|-sda4      8:4    0    4G  0 part  
| `-md125   9:125  0    4G  0 raid1 /tmp
`-sda5      8:5    0  1.8T  0 part  
  `-md124   9:124  0  1.8T  0 raid1 /
sdb         8:16   0  1.8T  0 disk  
|-sdb1      8:17   0    1M  0 part  
|-sdb2      8:18   0    1G  0 part  
| `-md127   9:127  0 1024M  0 raid1 /boot
|-sdb3      8:19   0    4G  0 part  
| `-md126   9:126  0    4G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
|-sdb4      8:20   0    4G  0 part  
| `-md125   9:125  0    4G  0 raid1 /tmp
`-sdb5      8:21   0  1.8T  0 part  
  `-md124   9:124  0  1.8T  0 raid1 /

First question, if I reboot the server it start correctly?
Second question, how can I fix the mdadm configuration?
The /etc/fstab is:
# /dev/md5
UUID=a25e04de-f396-4e27-9b41-5d32a336d5da   /           ext4        rw,relatime 0 1

# /dev/md2
UUID=366efbf7-4c4e-4f66-b8db-f619eadb3283   /boot       ext2        rw,relatime,block_validity,barrier,user_xattr,acl   0 2

# /dev/md4
UUID=8909bb22-47af-4374-b6ef-4f0187e842a9   /tmp        ext4        rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 2

# /dev/md3
UUID=0e658fcf-3603-44a2-a59b-b752e162aa43   none        swap        defaults,pri=-2 0 0

Below the output of ls -l /dev/md:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Dec 31  2020 10907523:root -> ../md124
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Dec 31  2020 10907523:swap -> ../md126
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Dec 31  2020 10907523:tmp -> ../md125
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Dec 31  2020 125_0 -> ../md127


Whats in your /etc/fstab? What persistent filesystems are currently mounted?

I added the /etc/fstab in the question

I think the problem occurred after rebooting the server, following which the device names changed. Can someone help me?

That these names were changed is perfectly normal. They are not stable and supposed to change, just like /dev/sdX names.
Stable are UUIDs (that's very good you're using them) and /dev/md/... symlinks. Run ls -l /dev/md/ to see them. Oh, you already did mdadm --examine --scan, that helped too.
Problem is that your /dev/mdX are hardcoded instead of being discovered on the fly or using stable symlinks; find and update there. I am not sure it's only mdadm.conf.
For instance, you may egrep -R md2 /etc/*; it will find all instances of the string md2 that need to be updated with some stable symlink; I would expect that other names will be easy to find somewhere nearby once you catch this one.
It's possible that logwatch or something else is stupid enough to blindly trust what's written in mdadm.conf and it doesn't know anything about modern Linux's udev behavior. You can just replace your arrays definitions in mdadm.conf with that mdadm --examine --scan output; it may fix the problem if that's the case.

Yes, you right UUIDs is the best way, but
I received the server from the provider with OS and raid already configured.
I added the output of ls -l on /dev/md to the question.
I also searched for the string md2 with egrep, but it only appears in the comments of fstab and mdadm.conf files.
It's actually unclear to me if the raid is currently working or not and what would happen if I simply rebooted the machine.
Furthermore, what would happen if I modified the mdadm configuration file with what was obtained from the scan?

Your RAID is perfectly working. /proc/mdadm is an ultimate evidence, it always shows an actual live state of arrays currently running in the system. All four show [UU], which means, no devices are missing and your data is safe. // Since, after your scan you've determined it's situated nowhere else (not counting the comment), /etc/mdadm.conf is the only place to mention "old" device names. That means, whatever induced the error message, it must have been found these names in it. The config update I suggested is essentially to specify the correct, stable device node names instead of "old".

Thanks Nikita, I'm new here so I can't upvote your answer, but it was helpful. I edit my mdadm.conf and everything seems to be working fine

You can accept it (a tick mark), that's a proper way to mark a question as solved.
